# Property 'staticAlert' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.ts

Tags: angular, angular-bootstrap, strict, viewchild

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

import {Subject} from 'rxjs';

import {debounceTime} from 'rxjs/operators';

import {NgbAlert} from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {


  staticAlertClose=false;
  successMesage='';

  private _success = new Subject<string>();


  @ViewChild('staticAlert', {static: false}) staticAlert: NgbAlert;

  @ViewChild('selfClosingAlert', {static: false}) selfClosingAlert: NgbAlert;


  ngOnInit(): void {

    //throw new Error('Method not implemented.');
    setTimeout(() => this.staticAlert.close(), 20000);
    this._success.subscribe(message => this.successMessage = message);
    this._success.pipe(debounceTime(5000)).subscribe(() => {
      if (this.selfClosingAlert) {
        this.selfClosingAlert.close();
      }
    });

  }

  close(alert: Alert) {

    this.alerts.splice(this.alerts.indexOf(alert), 1);

  }

  reset() {

    this.alerts = Array.from(ALERTS);

  }
  title = 'blog';
}
```

`enter code here`

I have enabled strict flag to help catch issues and I am getting this issue.
I wrote this code in app.component.ts file and got the code from https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/alert/examples
for auto close alerts example

Answer (score 0):

The way I got this working was by adding a default value. For some reason, the compiler doesn't like it when it's not defined from the jump, even though the Angular documentation doesn't have it defined from the jump.

This worked for me:

```
@ViewChild('selfClosingAlert', { static: false }) selfClosingAlert: NgbAlert | undefined;
```